# dispatch action and redirect by calling function without page reload in react redux ( Page Reload Problem )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**-- react,react-redux,react-router-dom  --**

if i use window.location.href = `/contact/edit/${id}`; works and redirect but problem is page reload and clear  state data .
but it's not work when i use this.props.history.push(`/contact/edit/${id}`);

there is any solution i want to redirect without page reload and also keep state data

```
class Contact extends Component {
 

  editContact = id => {
    const payload = {id:id,type:"setContact"}
    this.props.singleAction(payload)
    
    this.props.history.push(`/contact/edit/${id}`);

  }

  render() {
    const { id, name, email, phone } = this.props.contact;
    
    return (
      <div className="card card-body mb-3">
        <h4>
          {name}
            <i
              className="fas fa-pencil-alt"
              onClick={this.editContact.bind(this,id)}
              style={{
                cursor: 'pointer',
                float: 'right',
                color: 'black',
                marginRight: '1rem'
              }}
            />
        </h4>
          <ul className="list-group">
            <li className="list-group-item">Email: {email}</li>
            <li className="list-group-item">Phone: {phone}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default connect(null,{singleAction})(Contact);
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work, do you get errors?

Comment: If the same Contact component stays mounted when you click the "edit" button, you should not use the URL to change the ID. Normally this is handled in componentDidUpdate where you fetch the contact data for the id if it has changed.

Comment: his.props.history.push(`/contact/edit/${id}`);  this line not executed ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have `history` in your props.

Try to inject it with [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// ...

export default connect(null,{singleAction})(withRouter(Contact));
```